# Only few file names from sharepoint are displayed when searching using Microsoft Graph API DriveItems

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am using below code to search files in sharepoint:

```
 string cSecret = "XXXXXX";
 string cId = "XXXXXXX";
 var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
 var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
  .Create(cId)
  .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXX.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0")
  .WithClientSecret(cSecret)
  .Build();

    string requestUrl;
    GraphServiceClient graphClient =
    new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
    {
        var authResult = await confidentialClient
.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
.ExecuteAsync();

        // Add the access token in the Authorization header of the API request.
        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
    }));

    requestUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/search/query";

    var files = await graphClient.Drive.Root
        .Search("policy")
        .Request()
        .GetAsync();


    do
    {
        foreach (DriveItem file in files)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
        }

    } while (files.NextPageRequest != null && (files = await files.NextPageRequest.GetAsync()).Count > 0);
```

But, only one filename is shown in files.Name and  number of pages is only one next page is null.
I checked manually and using below api .

```
https://XXXX.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='policy'
```

and in sharepoint ,there are many results when i search policy.

Please help me getting all the files using above code.